# Is there a "wrap" function in R?

Tags: r

I was reading code on this page:
https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/31

```
upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 9))
```

Has anyone heard of a function called `wrap`? I always get:

> error: could not find function "wrap"

It does not belong to `base` package.

Comment: Try this: `library(sos); ???wrap` - this will give you references to many functions called `wrap()` in various R packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrap` is a function form the `GGally` package:

> Wraps a function with the given parameters. This allows for very
>   specific parameter arguements to be applied to each specific function.

You can find more [here.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/GGally.pdf)

(note the reference to ggally in your link url)

Comment: I get it now: I installed ggally, and tried to update to the newest version.  However, as my R does not support the "newest" version, I am actually using the older version of ggally that does not have the "wrap" function. Update to R 3.30 and ggally solved the issue.